# SQL Join Issues

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I wonder whether someone could help me please.

I've got a problem in trying to amalgamate information from two mySQL database tables.

The query that I've put together so far is shown below.

```
<?php 
require("phpfile.php"); 

// Start XML file, create parent node 

$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0"); 
$node = $dom->createElement("markers"); 
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node); 

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server 

$connection=mysql_connect ("hostname", $username, $password); 
if (!$connection) { die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());} 

// Set the active MySQL database 

$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection); 
if (!$db_selected) { 
die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error()); 
} 

$query = "SELECT findid,
                 findosgb36lat,
                 findosgb36lon,
                 findcategory,
                 findname,
                 finddescription
          FROM   finds
          WHERE  makepublic = 'Yes'
            AND  sites.sitetype,
                 sites.sitedescription,
                 sites.siteosgb36lat,
                 sites.osgb36lon";  
$result = mysql_query($query); 
if (!$result) { 
die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 

header("Content-type: text/xml"); 

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each 

while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
// ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE 
$node = $dom->createElement("marker"); 
$newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
$newnode->setAttribute("findosgb36lat",$row['findosgb36lat']); 
$newnode->setAttribute("findosgb36lon",$row['findosgb36lon']); 
$newnode->setAttribute("findcategory",$row['findcategory']); 
$newnode->setAttribute("findname",$row['findname']);
$newnode->setAttribute("finddescription",$row['finddescription']);
} 

echo $dom->saveXML(); 

?>
```

The problem I have is that I'm not sure how to pull all the records from the 'sites' table but only those records from the 'finds' table where the 'makepublic' value is 'yes'. I've done some research to see whether a specific join i.e. left or right will work, but because there is no common field between the tables I know that these won't work.

Could someone perhaps show me how I can get around this problem please.

Many thanks

Comment: If there's no common field between the tables, in what way are you expecting them to associate with each other?  Are you perhaps looking for UNION?

Comment: Sounds more like a [union](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) than a join, but without a common column how do you anticipate the data to align? (Unless I'm not understanding the marriage of the tables correctly)

Comment: What is the schema for each table? If they're the same or if you select equivalent fields, you can use a union.

Comment: p.s. Depending on performance it may make sense to only establish the DOM when you need it, not before you establish the database. (No use it creating a DOM if/when a SQL connection can't be established)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all many thanks for your help on this. I've been working on this today and have solved all the issues I had by using a 'UNION ALL' query. Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Making some **big** assumptions about table structures:

```
      SELECT s.site_id,
             s.sitetype,
             s.sitedescription,
             s.siteosgb36lat,
             s.osgb36lon,
             f.findid,
             f.findosgb36lat,
             f.findosgb36lon,
             f.findcategory,
             f.findname,
             f.finddescription
      FROM   sites s
      LEFT OUTER JOIN finds f on s.site_id = f.site_id and f.makepublic = 'Yes'
```

Comment: Hi, all many thanks for replying to my post. A 'Union' may be the way to go, I'm not too sure. The reason behind doing this is that I have lat and lng fields in the 'sites' table and another set in the 'finds' table which I want to try and amalgamate into one node line which I will then load into a HTML page. Kind regards

Comment: @IHRM: Seriously, as Jim H said, we really need to see the structures of the tables you are using if we are to be able to suggest a reasonable approach to querying them.

Comment: Hi, I have now added the table structures to my original post. Kind regards

Comment: @IHRM: where? I can't see them, and you aren't shown as having amended your original post.